# How do I reach accurate values using Newton-Raphson method?

Tags: c++, math

Here is a link to the problem.
http://www.spoj.com/problems/TRIGALGE/

The problem is quite simple and we only have to solve the given equation . I decided to try using Newton-Raphson method ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method ) .

Here is a link to my code that I had submitted but got a wrong answer-->http://ideone.com/dYev3P

I am unable to understand the logic behind the precision . 
For ,

```
a=1 b=1 c=20
x should be , x=19.441787
```

but I am getting

```
x=19.441786
```

I printed the whole series for 100 iterations but nowhere did I get the exact value . Please tell me the correct approach and how to get correct precision while dealing with Floating point integers .

Comment: Relevant information should be posted *here*. But I imagine that `x=19.441787` is surely not the exact answer either, and in fact, the exact answer cannot be written in any radix as a terminating numeral.

Comment: @Hurkyl , I think the down-vote was quite unnecessary , I know the exact answers can't be determined but that was not my question . Please go through the links that I have provided .

Comment: A question here should be self-contained; links can make sense for supplementary material, but not for the core of the question. (also, I did not downvote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea of Newton-Raphson is successive approximations. Within certain bounds, you hope that each approximation is better than the previous (though that's not entirely guaranteed, by any means).

As far as your code goes, you're using `float`s, which are only good for about 7 significant digits of precision. That gets you `17.44179` as being about the best you should really hope for (and, indeed, after rounding to 7 digits, that's exactly what you got).

If you really need that 8<sup>th</sup> digit of precision, you should use `double` instead of `float` as your data type. That doesn't change the fact that you're dealing with successive approximations, but it does mean you can expect around 15 digits of precision instead of only 7.

I should probably also note that computer floating point is almost always a matter of approximation in general. With the right libraries, you can approximate to hundreds or even trillions of digits, but when you deal with floating point, you shouldn't normally have an expectation that one specific answer is right, and other answers are wrong, even if they're nearly equal to the "right" one. Rather the contrary, you should expect minor variations as a rule (with "minor" being a relative term--i.e., acceptable errors are relative to the magnitude of the numbers involved.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jerry's answer don't forget to remove the `.f` after each `1.0` you have multiplied in order to treat them as floating point numbers. This and changing all your floats to double shall definitely do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you just change you `float` to `double` you do indeed get `19.441786710` already after iteration 7.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>    
void solve(int a,int b,int c){
    double x = 0.2 ;
    for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
        x = x*1.0 - ( ( (a*x*1.0 + ( b*sin(x)*1.0 ) )*1.0 - c*1.0  )/
           (a*1.0  + b*(cos(x))*1.0 ) ) ;
        std::cout << i << " " << x-19.441787 << std::endl;
    }
}
int main(){
    solve(1,1,20) ;
}
```